# Error when trying to decode json with Iterable in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, iterable

I'm trying to get this simple json response in Flutter, but getting this error **type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable< dynamic >'**. I found some people with the same error but the solutions it's not clearly to me. The error occurs on jsonDecode(response.body);, in debug mode, when reachs the response.body, the exception occurs.

```
{
"#bom": 4,
"#jantar": 3,
"#paris": 2,
}
```

My model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Hashtags> hashtagsFromJson(String str) => List<Hashtags>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Hashtags.fromJson(x)));

String hashtagsToJson(List<Hashtags> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Hashtags {
Hashtags({
    this.hashtag,
});

int? hashtag;

factory Hashtags.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hashtags(
    hashtag: json["hashtag"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "hashtag": hashtag,
};
}
```

and my get method:

```
Future<List<Hashtags>> getHashtagTop() async {

var url = Uri.parse(baseUrl + 'hashtagTop');

final Map<String, String> dataBody = new Map<String, String>();
dataBody['uid'] = appController.currentUser.value.id.toString();

try {
  http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonEncode(dataBody),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    Iterable jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Hashtags> listHashtagTop =
        jsonResponse.map((model) => Hashtags.fromJson(model)).toList();

    return listHashtagTop;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("ERRO_______________" + e.toString());
  return [];
}
}
```

So what is missing here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the complete Traceback.

Comment: `Map<String,dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your decoding function to this

```
 final results = [jsonDecode(response.body)];

List<Hashtags> listHashtagTop =
        results.map((model) => Hashtags.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

Try this and let you know

Comment: The error keep occuring :( '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: can you `print` this and check. `print(jsonDecode(response.body))` and `print(response.body)`

Comment: looks like a map `{
"#bom": 4,
"#jantar": 3,
"#paris": 2,
}` not a list

Comment: print(jsonDecode(response.body)): {#bom: 4, #jantar: 3, #paris: 2, #MuitoRuim: 1, #fusion: 1, #japa: 1, #france: 1, #10: 1, #mac: 1, #reparo: 1}
____________
print(response.body): {"#bom":4,"#jantar":3,"#paris":2,"#MuitoRuim":1,"#fusion":1,"#japa":1,"#france":1,"#10":1,"#mac":1,"#reparo":1}

Comment: @MateusFélix I edited my code try again. by the way, why do you try to return an `array`? your API return `json object` not a `json array`

Comment: @BISTech it worked!! The error stopped. Thank you. I change some things too, now it returning correctly.